# Google OAuth method AuthorizeAsync hangs when called from certain applications

Tags: c#, google-drive-api, google-oauth

I have a C# library I wrote the provides some helper functions to access a Google Drive.

The service constructor calls `AuthorizeAsync` as follows:

```
// get access token
var credential = GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(secrets, Scopes, key, CancellationToken.None, storageService).Result;
```

I have written unit tests for this, and the tests work when run from the unit test system. I have also used it in a Windows Service and again it works fine. I know this code works.

I've now tried to use it in an older application which has a lot more DLLs and references, and  when I call the method it just hangs and no exception is raised.

I strongly suspect that it's a DLL conflict somewhere, but without an exception or any errors in compilation, it's impossible to know what to change.

API versions:

```
  <package id="Google.Apis" version="1.8.2" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Google.Apis.Auth" version="1.8.2" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Google.Apis.Core" version="1.8.2" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Google.Apis.Drive.v2" version="1.8.1.1270" targetFramework="net45" />
```

Related libraries:

```
  <package id="log4net" version="2.0.3" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Bcl" version="1.1.9" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Bcl.Async" version="1.0.168" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Bcl.Build" version="1.0.14" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Net.Http" version="2.2.22" targetFramework="net45" />
```

Any pointers welcomed..

Answer (score 1):

Code didn't worked because app was hosted on IIS. There might be problem with IIS accessing the folder inside %appdata% folder. Token file is by default saved at %appdata% folder. I tried changing permission to that folder. I added Everyone,DefaultAppPool,I_USER,... but no success. There is also newer version of Google.Apis (1.8.2) which allows full path ( new FileDataStore(fullPath,true)) true means full path, but there is bug even there. It was not possible to user that constructor, because I always get error. So I decided my app should use IIS Express( In fact I created new project with authorization code inside). Go to solution properties and set your app use IIS Express.

Get cliendId (json file) from https://console.developers.google.com (choose web application) and set http:// localhost:48372 (or whatever your app port use) for javascript origins and http:// localhost:48372/authorize.aspx for redirect url. You should also find on the internet how to make your port static). Save your clientId file. (This step you probably already did)
As you use IIS express there should be no problem with AuthorizeAsync method. You will be promted to enter your credentials and choose your youtube account(or just choose account if you are already loged in). When you give your app permission you will be redirected to authorize.aspx. Your authorize aspx page should create new IAuthorization flow object with Client Secret property and DataStore proprty provided. Read code from URL using code= Request.Params["code"] and create UserCredential object.HttpClientInitializer property of youtubeService is of type UserCredential. Method you should use is something like var usercredential= flow.SomeMethodWhichReceives("user",code,CancelletionToken.None). After that the file containing refresh token is generated inside your  FileDataStore folder you specified.
When you have your refresh token you can do whatever you want because refresh token should last forever (unless manualy revoked). There is method which allows getting usercredential from refreshtoken, something like flow.getAccessTokenfromRefreshToken("user","your_refresh_token_string")
So, when yo have your refresh token and using method last method you will be able to access google youtube api. You also get possibility that other users upload to your youtube account using this aproach. If you are consered about content your users put on your account you can always make videos they uploaded private and change them to public when you verify them.

Some methods inside google youtube api require OAUTH2 authentication (get refresh token from client secret ->get access token from refresh token...),upload videos for example, but some like getvideos do not require. You can provided API key to your youtubeService conctructor instead of UserCredential

EDIT: There is also one more catch I forgot to mention (for those who thought this was all). When you give your app permission to access google api( just before you are reddirected to authorize.aspx), you will get error redirect_url mismatch, because there is somewhere in the url parametar redirect_url which does not match with redirect url you provided in your ClientId json,(port was different,at least, for some reason). Change this parametar so that is matched with redirect url you provided in clientId json.

Comment: Thanks for a very comprehensive input! I should add that I'm not using the file system for the Tokens, I have my own IDataStore implementation that uses memory, so file access was not an issue. You can read more on my blog at http://conficient.wordpress.com/2014/06/18/using-google-drive-api-with-c-part-2/ it may help you.